# on Mac, how to export pdf for certain pages

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

on Mac, how to export pdf for certain pages.

For example, I have a pdf file for 40 pages, I just want to export page 10 and 11.
Can anyone help me?thnaks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. Open the PDF in Preview.
2. Turn on the sidebar. [image]
3. Turn on thumbnails. [image]
4. Select first desired page in sidebar and copy it (`command` + c).
5. Click *File > New From Clipboard* or type `command` + n.
6. Turn on the sidebar and thumbnails in the new document.
7. Drag remaining pages from original document sidebar to the new document sidebar.
8. ???
9. Profit.

Comment: Dragging every page separately is very laborious. Step 5's keyboard shortcut is wrong (at least on Mac OS X 10.6).

Comment: @DanielBeck, Correct, it should be `command` + n. And LOL @ *"very laborious"*.

Comment: Not an issue with 2 pages, but how about 50? From your description I assume you copy them one by one.

Comment: @DanielBeck, No, I either edit the original, deleting unwanted pages, or use your method.

Comment: That's cooooool, preview makes it more simple.

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively you can open your document and choose *File > Print…* . Set the page range desired as if you would print the document, and then click on the *PDF* button and choose *Save as PDF…*

Answer (score 11):

Open the PDF in Preview, show the sidebar's thumbnail view (`Cmd-Opt-2`), and select the pages you want to have as a separate document in the sidebar (you can select multiple pages by holding `Cmd` down while clicking, or select a range of pages by selecting the first, then selecting the last while while holding down `Shift`).

Then drag and drop them to the desktop. A new PDF file will be created with just those pages.

Alternatively, press `Cmd-C` to copy the selected pages in the sidebar to the clipboard and create a new document from clipboard by pressing `Cmd-N`. Don't forget to save (`Cmd-S`)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method:

1. Choose print from file menu that will bring the print dialog
2. On Pages option choose Range or Single as appropriate
3. At the bottom PDF button click and choose 'Open PDF in preview'. This will open the chosen pages as a PDF in preview.
4. Now choose File/Export and on the dialog choose Format as JPEG or PNG appropriate.

Comment: This is really the only effective way of doing it from Preview.

Answer (score 2):

A variation: command-click in the sidebar to select the two pages you want. *File > Print Selected Pages*. Save as PDF from the PDF pulldown button on the lower left of the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can  select a range via SHIFT OR you can use Command button to select noncontiguous pages. Then follow the directions for creating a new document as above.